# How to call a method

Tags: java, android, class, methods, return

How to call a method in a different class and get the result in the MainActivity.

I am Calling a Get method in my API. But I am not sure how to pass the result data back to mainActivity:

My code

**CallAPI class :**

```
...
public void Get() {
        Log.i(TAG, "GET()");
        // GET method example
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            protected String doInBackground(Void... parameters) {
                API api = new API(mApiKey, mApiSecret);

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();       
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", mApiKey));                     

                return api.get("category", params);
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  // *** >I NEED THIS result< ***
                Log.i(TAG + " - APIRESULT", "GET() => " + result);
            }

        }.execute();
    }//end Get
...
```

**MainActivity class:**

```
...
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

           mCallApi.Get();

...
```

So in MainActivity I can run the method, but not sure how to the result date in here.

Thanks

Comment: provide return type to the method.. and when you call that method... store response in string object..

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface.  Since the code is asynchronous you can't use return value.

```
interface myCallBack(){
    public void callBack( String result );
}

public void Get(final myCallBack callback) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GET()");
    // GET method example
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        protected String doInBackground(Void... parameters) {
            API api = new API(mApiKey, mApiSecret);

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();       
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", mApiKey));                     

            return api.get("category", params);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  // *** >I NEED THIS result< ***
            Log.i(TAG + " - APIRESULT", "GET() => " + result);
            callback.callBack( result );
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

The from the class:

...

```
get( new myCallBack(){ 
   public void callBack(String result ){
   //do something with result.
   }
} 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A. public void Get() {} this doesnt have any arragment for returning a value back to caller
B. even it has a return type, its irrelevnt, since you are spawning a AsyncTask inside method, return
   value is irrelevant to outcome of operation.

Now coming to your problem, this can be solved via Observer design pattern. here is my response for similar question sometime back, go through it. this will solve your issue. [Observer Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470192/android-class-with-sub-class-asynctask-wait-for-the-postexecute-before-returning/20470767#20470767)